# How to add more than one element to an addClass() method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add more than one div element to the same class with the addClass() in jQuery. For example I have this:

```
<script>
$('.divOne, .divTwo').addClass('style');
</script>
```

But this does not work. The class 'style' does not apply to classes 'divOne' and 'divTwo' (it only applies to one at a time). How can I make this possible without adding each one separately to the 'style' class?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/692Q8/

Comment: @j08691 For some kind of unknown reason or typo I made it did not work but now it does, thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

i think you´re wrong,

heres a working example

```
$('.divOne, .divTwo').addClass('style');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37Y5N/1/

Comment: @john Smith, as I specified above, it works now for some unknown reason, thx for helping out ...

Comment: @j08691 a "not-working" question on a working thing is a working thing, so a working thing is the answer

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make this possible without adding each one separately to the
>   'style' class?

What's wrong with adding it separately? Surely

```
$('.divOne').addClass('style');
$('.divTwo').addClass('style');
```

should be fine?

Comment: It is fine, and it works, but I have a lot of classes which I need to apply to the specific 'style'. And I can't just encapsulate them in one div class. This is the reason ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works great actually.

```
$('.divOne, .divTwo').addClass('style');
```

You can even try adding many classes, like so:

```
$('.divOne, .divTwo').addClass('style1 style2');
```

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Kr7s/1/)**